# XspInputText renderer class

Tags: xpages

I am trying to extend the XspInputText renderer. Is it possible to see what IBM put into the renderer class.

Can i find it somewhere on the server or client? I searched for a documentation about it but couldnt  find one.

Answer (score 3):

You can find compiled class

```
com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText
```

in folder

```
..\Server\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.extsn_...
```

in

```
lwpd.xsp.extsn.jar
```

Use a tool of your choice to see the code.

Comment: That's in the same jar file: com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.InputTextRenderer.

Comment: Can you please  also tell me where to find the DataSource class.

Answer (score 1):

As Knut mentioned, you have to choose a tool of your choice to see the code.
The renderer can be found in the class

```
com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.InputTextRenderer
```

If you want to register your own class, you have to add it to the faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config>
   <render-kit>
      <renderer>
         <component-family>javax.faces.Input</component-family>
         <renderer-type>javax.faces.Text</renderer-type>
         <renderer-class>your.renderer.class.YourInputTextRenderer</renderer-class>
     </renderer>
  </render-kit>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Thx thats what i am looking for. Where would i find this class?

Comment: Thx found it. its in the same jar.